# Draw N number of circles on material in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, webgl

I have 3d object of necktie in my three js scene and my goal is to add a material to it with many circles of different sizes, colors and with no collisions.

I know it could be easily done by loading a texture with the circles, but I have one limitation:
I want to generate unique texture for every user, so the circles should always be randomized and the amount of the circles depends on user’s level (i.e. 1 lvl = 1 circle, max 100lvl)

I was thinking about several solutions:

1. generate a randomized circles data on three js side and pass the information to the vertex shader and from there to fragment shader so it could draw the circles on the texture accordingly to the data. But I am not sure how to do it in a parallel way, the way glsl works. I know I should avoid if conditions as much as possible for performance optimization so I have no ideas
2. draw on a fly additional html canvas with needed circles and use it as a texture. But I am not sure how to save the canvas information to the buffer and use it as a material later
3. maybe three js have built in solutions?

Thank you in advance

[image: Example of the texture]

Comment: Option number 2 is indeed doable, and Three.js makes it quite easy once you have generated the canvas you want. See https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture.

If you are familiar with shader programming, another approach might be to define a custom material on your tie and draw random circles on it in the fragment shader. No need to think about parallelism. Just give it a uniform for deterministic randomness and another for the level, and let the fragment shader decide which circles to be rendered where.

Comment: @Berthur thank you! I have decided to go with a canvas method as it seems has more control than glsl. But now I have faced another issue - the dots on the canvas are drawn at random locations, but I have UV map of the tie and would like to draw the circles exactly within the UV islands because I need the exact number of circles to be on the tie, is there a way to combine canvas and UV mapping so control the areas where I can draw?

Comment: I don't know about that. But if the tie is completely flat, maybe you can do some smart sampling in javascript to make sure you get the right number of circles inside the tie shape in the canvas? Rejection sampling, perhaps.